# consulta json en mongo db desde python (anaconda)

Tags: python, json, mongodb

Tengo una colección ('tweets', json) en mongo db y quiero saber  aquellos deportistas que tienen alguno de sus tweets geolocalizados realizando la consulta desde python (anaconda). La conexión a la colección se hace sin problemas, pero la consulta que SI funciona en mongo db no la puedo realizar desde python , me sale el error 'invalid sintax'...

-Consulta desde mongo db, SI funciona:

```js
db.getCollection('tweets').find( 
    {geo:{$exists: true, $ne:null}},  
    {Deportista:1, Longitud_WGS84:{$arrayElemAt:["$geo.coordinates",1]},Latitud_WGS84:{$arrayElemAt:["$geo.coordinates",0]}}
)
```

Hago esa misma consulta desde anaconda y no funciona por error de sintaxis......

El objetivo es a partir de esa consulta crear un archivo shapefile.

Gracias,

Juanjo

Comment: ¿Estás usando exactamente la misma consulta? Porque de ser así, ese es el error, la estructura y métodos del [`shell`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/index.html) de Mongo no están disponibles en [`pymongo`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/). Debes realizar la consulta de acuerdo a la documentación del controlador adecuado. Saludos

Comment: Entiendo. Imaginaba que sería por eso pero he realizado otras consultas muy básicas y si han funcionado sin cambiar de estructura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar una consulta a una Base de Datos [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com) usando el controlador para MongoDB de Python: [`pymongo`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/).

Sin embargo, al realizar la consulta usando la misma sintaxis del [`shell`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/index.html) de MongoDB se recibe un error.

Resulta que los métodos y la sintaxis del `shell` de MongoDB no son los mismos que los métodos y la sintaxis del controlador `pymongo`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, pero requiere estudiar y leer la documentación del controlador `pymongo`.

En la `shell` de MongoDB tienes una consulta a la colección llamada `tweets`, mediante:

```js
db.getCollection('tweets').find( 
    {geo:{$exists: true, $ne:null}},  
    {Deportista:1, Longitud_WGS84:{$arrayElemAt:["$geo.coordinates",1]},Latitud_WGS84:{$arrayElemAt:["$geo.coordinates",0]}}
)
```

En `pymongo` no existe ningún método llamado [`getCollection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/index.html) (ya el mismo nombre del método en *camelCase* indica que no sería algo usual en Python).

En `pymongo` puedes hacer uso de la siguiente estructura para referirte a una colección:

```py
# usando la notación de punto:
db.tweets

# usando la notación de corchetes:
db['tweets']
```

La segunda opción es muy útil cuando deseamos usar un valor dinámico para la colección, por ejemplo:

```py
mi_coleccion = 'tweets'
# ...
db[mi_coleccion]
# ...
```

Por otro lado, el filtro y la proyección que usas en el `shell` de MongoDB debes adaptarlo para que sea un *diccionario* en Python. Si bien la sintaxis es algo parecida, no es lo mismo, ya que al fin y al cabo un [Objeto de Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object) no es igual a un [Diccionario de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Entonces, convirtiendo la estructura del filtro tendríamos:

```py
# El siguiente filtro es un diccionario válido en Python:
{ 'geo': { '$exists': True, '$ne': None} },

# La siguiente proyección es un diccionario válido en Python:
{ 
  'Deportista': 1,
  'Longitud_WGS84': { '$arrayElemAt':['$geo.coordinates', 1] },
  'Latitud_WGS84': { '$arrayElemAt': ['$geo.coordinates', 0] }
}
```

Así, tu consulta en `pymongo` podría verse como la siguiente:

```py
coleccion = 'tweets'
filtro = { 'geo': { '$exists': True, '$ne': None} }
proyeccion = { 
  'Deportista': 1,
  'Longitud_WGS84': { '$arrayElemAt':['$geo.coordinates', 1] },
  'Latitud_WGS84': { '$arrayElemAt': ['$geo.coordinates', 0] }
}

resultado = db[coleccion].find(filtro, proyeccion)
```

Como puedes observar el [tipo `null`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html) de un documento [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-bson) es equivalente al tipo [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) de Python. Además los valores booleanos de Javascript, debes escribirlos como sus equivalentes en Python (`true -> True`).

Para obtener una lista de equivalencias entre los tipos BSON y los tipos de Python, puedes consultar la [tabla de equivalencias](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/index.html?highlight=null#module-bson)

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio, cuando retome ese tema lo pruebo y te digo.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, lo he modificado tal y como indicas. No hay ningún error y se ejecuta la sentencia completa. El problema es que intento visualizar el resultado (print(resultado)) y no muestra nada.....

Comment: Claro, porque resultado es un [`cursor`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html), el cual es un tipo de objeto *iterable*. Puedes verificar haciendo: `type(resultado)` y te debe mostrar: `<class 'pymongo.cursor.Cursor'>`. Para ver los documentos podrías hacer algo como: `for doc in resultado:` y luego puedes imprimir cada documento con `print(doc)`. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, he podido ver el resultado. Ahora estoy peleando para exportar esa consulta a un archivo geoespacial *.shp. TO BE CONTINUED.....

Comment: Si la respuesta es válida, no olvides marcarla como tal. Eso te da puntos a ti y por supuesto a mi, además otros usuarios pueden usarla como respuesta para un problema similar. Saludos